# dlfcn is not linked by cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I'm working on Go code that invokes C, and this is the current set up.

- build system: bazel with cgo
- C code calls `dlsym()`
- added `// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl` in Go code above the line `import "C"`
- Added `#include <dlfcn.h>` in C code
- execution command with `verbose_failures` enabled and it looks like `LDFLAGS -ldl` is not set.

```
cd /usr/local/home/<REMOVED> && \
  exec env - \
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOARCH=amd64 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOPATH='' \
    GOROOT=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild-ST-03006dd95b75/bin/external/io_bazel_rules_go/stdlib_ \
    GOROOT_FINAL=GOROOT \
    PATH=external/llvm_toolchain/bin:/bin:/usr/bin \
  bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-3CAA6C3F-ST-f279a0ffb7f5/bin/external/go_sdk/builder '-param=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild-ST-4a519fd6d3e4/bin/scanner/<REMOVED>.params' -- -extld external/llvm_toolchain/bin/cc_wrapper.sh -race '-buildid=redacted' -extldflags '--target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lm -no-canonical-prefixes -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--build-id=md5 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -l:libstdc++.a --sysroot=external/debian_bullseye_sysroot'
```

- build error:

```
external/go_sdk/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running external/llvm_toolchain/bin/cc_wrapper.sh failed: exit status 1
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: dlsym
```

How can I fix the missing dependency dlfcn / dlsym() with cgo? Thanks!

Comment: I admit I know nothing of go or bazel, but `go build` does work for me: https://github.com/lzsiga/minimal-go-example